Migrate an active DNS name from one Azure App Service to another
Accordingly to this article, you should be able to bind a custom domain preemptively to an App Service. So I have added the TXT record to the DNS, but when adding the custom domain on the new App Service I still get validation error. I tells that the hostname conflicts with an already existing hostname of another App Service. And that is of course true.
So it seems there is now way preemtively add the binding and thus no way to migrate a hostname to another App Service without downtime. Or am I missing something?
(Also it looks like you can only add a Managed SSL Certificate after the CNAME records is changed, so that is also preventing from migration without downtime.)
